# NSNumberFormatter only rounds to 3 decimal places

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to use `NSNumberFormatter` to round a number to 5 decimal places in an iPhone app, but `[formatter stringFromNumber:]` always returns strings rounded to 0.001 (3 decimal places). What am I doing wrong?

```
formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setRoundingMode:NSNumberFormatterRoundHalfUp];
[formatter setSecondaryGroupingSize:3];
[formatter setRoundingIncrement:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.00001]];
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Try [-setMaximumFractionDigits:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumberFormatter/setMaximumFractionDigits:) and [-setMinimumFractionDigits:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumberFormatter/setMinimumFractionDigits:)

These configure the number of digits after the decimal separator.

Comment: Thank you Nathan! I must be missing something while reading the docs, but how do these differ from setMaximumSignificantDigits: and setMinimumSignificantDigits: (aside from the word Significant <grin>)?

Comment: Fraction digits are numbers after the decimal place. Significant digits is the overall precision of the number.

So 12.345 has 5 significant digits and 3 fraction digits.
Whereas 0.0012 has 2 significant digits and 4 fraction digits.

set(min/max)SignificantDigits: are useful for scientific style output: 123000 would be 1.23E5 with 3 significant digits.

Comment: Note that if using [ formatter setMinimumSignificantDigits ] you must first call [ formatter setUsesSignificantDigits: TRUE ];

Answer (score 2):

Try [formatter setFormat:@"0.00000"]; instead of setRoundingIncrement:.

Comment: I don't think setFormat: is available on the iPhone. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416037/iphone-nsnumberformatter-setformat

Comment: Actually, I take that back. setFormat:@"0.00000" does work, but it doesn't round... I always get 5 numbers past the decimal--e.g., 0.10000, when I really only want 0.1 in that case.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood what you were trying to accomplish.

Comment: I wasn't that clear about what I was trying to accomplish. Your response was helpful. Thank you.