# NSDecimalNumber zeros following decimal point (iPhone SDK)

Tags: ios, nsdecimalnumber

I have the following code

```
(...)
numberStyle = [NSDecimalNumberHandler decimalNumberHandlerWithRoundingMode:NSRoundPlain
                                                                     scale:2
                                                          raiseOnExactness:NO
                                                           raiseOnOverflow:NO
                                                          raiseOnUnderflow:NO
                                                       raiseOnDivideByZero:NO];

strThree = textFieldThree.text;
strThree = [strThree stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@""];

fieldOneDNa = (NSDecimalNumber *)[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:strThree];
oneHundred = (NSDecimalNumber *)[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"100"];
fieldOneDN = [fieldOneDNa decimalNumberByDividingBy:oneHundred
                                       withBehavior:numberStyle];

firstStepReturn = [fieldOneDN stringValue];
textFieldThree.text = firstStepReturn;
(...)
```

I would like to be able to have firstStepReturn have 2 digits following the decimal point even if they are .00 or .*0. For example, if 323.390 was inputted into the textfield "textFieldThree", it would be processed and returned to the textfield as 3233.90. At the moment, it is displaying as 3233.9.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 18):

NSDecimalNumber subclasses NSNumber so you just need to use NSNumberFormatter

```
 NSDecimalNumber * dn = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"1234.5"];
 NSNumberFormatter * nf = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
 [nf setMinimumFractionDigits:2];
 [nf setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
 NSString *ns  = [nf stringFromNumber:dn];
```

Simples

Comment: there is also help here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/810161/nsnumberformatter-only-rounds-to-3-decimal-places

Answer (score 4):

Why not use `textFieldThree.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",[fieldOneDN floatvalue]];`

(or something similar - sorry I'm on a PC right now so can't test this)

Comment: Thanks, but I was trying to avoid using a float because it was inaccurate when large numbers were used. Do you have any other suggestions?