# NSNumberFormatter setFormat error

Tags: ios

Working on my first iOS app. I think that this code should work, but I get the following error. Maybe I am missing an import or something?

`No visible @interface for 'NSNumberFormatter' declares the selector'setFormat'`

```
NSNumberFormatter* formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setFormat:@"#0.00"];
```

Comment: use [formatter setPositiveFormat:@"00.00E+00"];

Comment: setFormat is not available on iOS.
This question should help:
[iPhone NSNumberFormatter setFormat][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416037/iphone-nsnumberformatter-setformat

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387330/no-visible-interface-for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cann't call setFormat: for NSNumberFormatter.

Some sample code:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
NSString *string = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:123456789]];
NSLog(@"Formatted number string:%@",string);
```

numberStyle enum:

```
enum {  
    NSNumberFormatterNoStyle = kCFNumberFormatterNoStyle,
    NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle = kCFNumberFormatterDecimalStyle,
    NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle = kCFNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle,
    NSNumberFormatterPercentStyle = kCFNumberFormatterPercentStyle,
    NSNumberFormatterScientificStyle = kCFNumberFormatterScientificStyle,
    NSNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle = kCFNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle
};
```

reslut for each numberStyle:

```
[1243:403] Formatted number string:123456789
[1243:403] Formatted number string:123,456,789
[1243:403] Formatted number string:￥123,456,789.00
[1243:403] Formatted number string:-539,222,988%
[1243:403] Formatted number string:1.23456789E8
[1243:403] Formatted number string:one hundred twenty-three million four hundred fifty-six thousand seven hundred eighty-nine
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't set the format as you provided here. Set the number format as given below

```
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle];
//or other styles like NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle,NSNumberFormatterPercentStyle
```

or you can create a custom number format as

```
[formatter setPositiveFormat:@"#0.00"];
```

A nice tutorial is given here

http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/06/14/using-number-formatters.html